# Django UNIQUE constraint failed: core_organization.name

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I have a model called Organization inside core/models.py. I am trying to implement CRUD Ajax on a single page. Inspired by this [post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html). Every time I save an object of this model I get this error as shown below. I want to have multiple organizations that are unique.

**core/models.py**

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gstin = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_billed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} Organization'
```

**core/forms.py**

```py
class OrganizationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Organization
        fields = ('name', 'address', 'state', 'city', 'zipcode', 'country', 'gstin')
```

**core/views.py**

```py
def save_organization_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            stock = form.save(commit=False)
            stock.user = request.user
            stock.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            organizations = Organization.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('core/includes/partial_organization_list.html', {
                'organizations': organizations
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def organization_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrganizationForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = OrganizationForm()
    return save_organization_form(request, form, 'core/includes/partial_organization_create.html')
```

**templates/base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block head_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block extra_head %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo One' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'font/flaticon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}

    {% if messages %}
    <div class="text-center">
      <strong>Messages:</strong>
      <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{message}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block extra_body %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block javascript %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**templates/core/organization_list.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block javascript %}
  <script src="{% static 'organizations/js/organizations.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <h1 class="page-header">Organizations</h1>

<!-- BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION -->
  <p>
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary js-create-book"
            data-url="{% url 'organization_create' %}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      New Organization
    </button>
  </p>

  <table class="table" id="book-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Zipcode</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Billing Active</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% include 'core/includes/partial_organization_list.html' %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

<!-- THE MODAL WE WILL BE USING -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-book">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**templates/core/partial_organization_list.html**

```
{% for organization in organizations %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ organization.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ organization.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ organization.address }}</td>
    <td>{{ organization.state }}</td>
    <td>{{ organization.city }}</td>
    <td>{{ organization.zipcode }}</td>
    <td>{{ organization.country }}</td>
    <td>{{ organization.is_billed }}</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-warning btn-sm js-update-book"
              data-url="{% url 'organization_update' organization.id %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
      </button>
      <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-danger btn-sm js-delete-book"
              data-url="{% url 'organization_delete' organization.id %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% empty %}
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8" class="text-center bg-warning">No Organization</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**static/organizations/js/organizations.js**

```
$(function () {

  $(".js-create-book").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/profile/organization/create/',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-book").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  });

});


$("#modal-book").on("submit", ".js-book-create-form", function () {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: form.attr("method"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.form_is_valid) {
          $("#book-table tbody").html(data.html_book_list);  // <-- Replace the table body
          $("#modal-book").modal("hide");  // <-- Close the modal
        }
        else {
          $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });


  $(".js-create-book").click(function () {
  var btn = $(this);  // <-- HERE
  $.ajax({
    url: btn.attr("data-url"),  // <-- AND HERE
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
      $("#modal-book").modal("show");
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
    }
  });
});


$(function () {

  /* Functions */

  var loadForm = function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: btn.attr("data-url"),
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-book").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  };

  var saveForm = function () {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: form.attr("method"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.form_is_valid) {
          $("#book-table tbody").html(data.html_book_list);
          $("#modal-book").modal("hide");
        }
        else {
          $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  };


  /* Binding */

  // Create book
  $(".js-create-book").click(loadForm);
  $("#modal-book").on("submit", ".js-book-create-form", saveForm);

  // Update book
  $("#book-table").on("click", ".js-update-book", loadForm);
  $("#modal-book").on("submit", ".js-book-update-form", saveForm);

  // Delete book
  $("#book-table").on("click", ".js-delete-book", loadForm);
  $("#modal-book").on("submit", ".js-book-delete-form", saveForm);

});
```

And when I add a new organization I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: core_organization.name
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You must have same organization name in database which you are filling again on your form. either you change the older name via admin or change what you're submitting in form.

Comment: I get this error the very first time I create an organization object.

Comment: Check all your **migrations** file and look if there is any `default` you might've set for `name `  field. If there is then you will have to drop your database or set different `default` which you can achieve by random id generators.

Comment: So now strangely this error disappears after adding multiple organizations. Not sure why the very first time only I get this error. I checked the migrations file 0001_initial.py and there's no default set for name field ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)),

Comment: I'd recommend changing your create view to : `form = OrganizationForm(request.POST or None)` instead of checking whether you receive a POST directly.  There are bugs that come up when passing an empty `request.POST` to Django forms, and `request.POST or None` prevents them.

Comment: Also, `max_length=1000` is pointless because `CharFields` can only have 255 characters.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Still does'nt make a difference. I get the same error. If I remove the unique=True from name field then the organization object is being updated twice.

Comment: I could not reproduce your error. Maybe it would be useful to also post your html and your js file. Is it possible that your script / html is sending the data to the view twice?

Comment: @Chris I suspect the same, maybe the js code is sending data twice. I'm not able to debug at the moment. I have updated my code above. Would love to see your findings. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @abicrazieeee If I read your js file correctly there are 3 ajax calls to load your modal (2 ```$(".js-create-book").click(function ()``` and 1 ```load_form```) and 2 functions bound to the form submit (```$("#modal-book").on("submit"``` and ```save_form``)`.

Comment: @Chris I've been following this https://github.com/sibtc/simple-ajax-crud , could you update the right content on js file below and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @abicrazieeee The bottom part of your js file is indeed the same as in your link, the top part adds the duplicates. Put it all in an answer, thx.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for spotting the duplicates! I have accepted your answer for now. However, I haven't tested the code yet. Will get back if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your javascript file contains duplicate ajax calls.

There are 3 calls to create your modal:

```
$(function () {

  $(".js-create-book").click(function () {
```

at the top of your js file. Then the same function in the middle of your js file. And

```
var loadForm = function ()
```

which your binding to the click event at the bottom of your script.

In addition there are two functions handling the submission of the form data:

```
$("#modal-book").on("submit", ".js-book-create-form", function ()
```

in the top part and

```
 var saveForm = function ()
```

in the bottom part.

The duplicate regarding the submission of the form can cause the unique constraint error because you are submitting the same data twice. The duplication of the loading of the modal probably does not cause any noticable errors, but is unnecessary load.

The bottom part of your javascript file, i.e. the part beginning with

```
$(function () {

  /* Functions */
```

should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having this issue, because of the `unique=True` constraint on your `name` field

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

This means that the name is going to be unique for all users, and you will keep getting `UNIQUE constraint failed` error everytime you add the same name for different users.

---

To solve this, I suggest using [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) meta option.
All you have to do, is removing the `unique` constraint from name field, and adding `Meta` class with the `unique_toghether` option to include both the `user_id` and `name` fields.

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None)
    is_billed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} Organization'

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['name', 'user_id']
```

Then, `python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate`.

The `UNIQUE` constraint going to remain, but it is going to be for all `Organization` names related for one user.

If **USER1** have organization **ORG1**, and tried to add another **ORG1**, it is going to fail, but if **USER2** added **ORG1** it is going to work successfully.

Comment: I still get this error after modifying as you suggested "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: core_organization.name, core_organization.user_id".

Comment: I think the problem is in views.py when I save the form with `commit=False`. Maybe it is updating twice with the same name and hence unique constraint failed error. Here is my complete traceback [Link](https://pastebin.com/qyDf1gLk)

Comment: Can you check the data being passed to the view, maybe the organization data being passed is always the same, which makes it throw this error

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the instance rather than form object, Create separate endpoint/logic for updating instance and an separate endpoint/logic to create objects using form

**views.py**

```
def save_organization_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            stock = form.instance
            stock.user = request.user
            stock.something = request.something
            stock.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            organizations = Organization.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('core/includes/partial_organization_list.html', {
                'organizations': organizations
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def organization_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrganizationForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = OrganizationForm()
    return save_organization_form(request, form, 'core/includes/partial_organization_create.html')
```